# How to do DateTime Comparison in C# Entity Function?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, date, datetime

I have certain date time saved in my database, my requirement is to get only those records which are newer than saved date-time.

I tried this code

```
DateTime last_date_time_saved = GetLastDateTimeFromDB();

List<Item> li = con.Items.Where(p => p.TimeModified > last_date_saved).ToList();
return li;
```

But it causes error Could not execute the specified command:

> Error parsing Date value [26/04/2015 16:42:56]."}

I have tried Convert.ToDateTime function but it still does not resolve the problem.

What is the best way to compare date time in this case?

Comment: Which variable that you try to parse? What is the definition of `GetLastDateTimeFromDB` method? Is `26/04/2015 16:42:56` a `string` or something?

Comment: GetLastDateTimeFromDB is returning a DateTime Object.

Comment: Where does `last_date_saved` come from? Is it a typo?

Comment: It is coming from SQL Server Database table from a DateTime coulmn which has Datetime value saved for example 23-04-2015 16:28:24

Comment: who is the champ rated -1 and did not have answer of this question?

Comment: Is `last_date_saved` different to `last_date_time_saved`? If so why did you show us `last_date_time_saved` being set when it is not used in the following line? While I wasn't the -1 voter, maybe they did it because you have not included enough code to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible issue I can see:

It may be including the square braces ('[' and ']') when parsing the string?

```
string value = "[26/04/2015 16:42:56]";
string safeValue = value.Remove(0, 1).Remove(value.Length - 2);
```

This will remove the braces, leaving "26/04/2015 16:42:56", which for me, works fine.